# APA Citation Quote + End of Sentence

Tags: quotes, citation

How do we correctly (APA style) end a sentence that ends in a quote and requires a citation?

> The manual explains it as, "a method for doing something (author, year)."

or

> The manual explains it as, "a method for doing something."  (author, year) 
>       Next sentence begins....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is correct. The citation goes outside the quote (it’s not something they said!) but within the period. You may also need to include a page number if the source has them:

> If you are directly quoting from a work, you will need to include the author, year of publication, and page number for the reference (preceded by "p."). Introduce the quotation with a signal phrase that includes the author's last name followed by the date of publication in parentheses.
>
> > According to Jones (1998), "Students often had difficulty using APA style, especially when it was their first time" (p. 199).
>
> If the author is not named in a signal phrase, place the author's last name, the year of publication, and the page number in parentheses after the quotation.
>
> <sub>[Purdue OWL — In-Text Citations: The Basics](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/apa_style/apa_formatting_and_style_guide/in_text_citations_the_basics.html)</sub>